# Displaying data from mongoskin through HTML

Tags: mongodb, mongoskin

I am using mongodb to store data and i wrote a simple js script using mongoskin to query and retrieve data from a collection and it works fine...

```
var db = require('mongoskin').db('winter.ceit.uq.edu.au/openbeacon');
var time = 0;
var tagid = 1101;
db.collection('set1').find({tag : {'$elemMatch': {id: tagid,name :"reader07"}}},function(err, result) {
if (err) throw err;
    result.each(function(err, band) {
        console.log(band.tag);
        time += band.time;
        });
});
```

However i need a way to integrate this functionality into a webpage...so say i press a button on the page, the js script runs and the queried data is displayed on the webpage. When i try using this javascript in a HTML file, it erros saying "module not found" since im referencing the index.js for mongoskin and mongodb as the source in my html file.....

Please lemme know what are the ways (preferably the simplest ways) to do this.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking for example applications

here is one

https://github.com/christkv/tic-tac-toe-steps